# New Mail Arrived notification Kmail + Jovie Speech customizing

Tags: linux, kde, kmail, text-to-speech

When a new message arrives, Kmail has ability to speak! Which is great but not enough: I don't want to listen to a standard text but have a proper functionality:

When a new message arrives, Jovie should say

> New Message arrived from Linus Torvalds

(if Linus Torvalds is in the Address Book, falling back to email@domain  without the TLD `.com`)

Or:

> Email about `%MSG_SUBJECT`

Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry for not answering in so long.  I did look into this, and it
seems the kmail notifications don't provide that detailed information.
 Here I can set the kmail new message notification to say either "New
mail has arrived" or some custom text or "new mail has arrived x in
folder y..." but nothing about sender.  I suggest filing a bug against
kmail for this wish to be added then we can handle speaking that
detailed information.

Best Regards,
Jeremy  (Jeremy Whiting <jpwhiting@kde.org>)

Comment: reported as bug -> https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=769546